# Replace a substring in a string except when the string is inside quotes

Tags: java, regex

Regex dialect: Java
The problem: given a string, replace all occurrences of a substring inside it, except when these occurrences are inside quotes.

Example1:

```
string: "test substr 'test substr' substr"
substring: "substr"
replacement: "YYYY"
output: "test YYYY 'test substr' YYYY"
```

Example2:

```
string: "test sstr 'test sstr' sstr"
substring: "substr"
replacement: "YYYY"
output: "test sstr 'test sstr' sstr"
```

Example3:

```
string: "test 'test substr'"
substring: "substr"
replacement: "YYYY"
output: "test 'test substr'"
```

This is my best try thus far:

```
Regex: ((?:[^']*'[^']+')*?[^']*?)substring
Replace: $1replacement
```

The problem with it is that it needs a substring outside the quotes after the last string within the quotes otherwise it doesn't work, so Example3 will fail (output: "test 'test YYYY'").

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        String[] tests = {
                "test substr 'test substr' substr",
                "test sstr 'test sstr' sstr",
                "test 'test substr'"
        };

        String regex = "substr(?=([^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)";

        for(String t : tests) {
            System.out.println(t.replaceAll(regex, "YYYY"));
        }
    }
}
```

prints:

```
test YYYY 'test substr' YYYY
test sstr 'test sstr' sstr
test 'test substr'
```

Note that this does not work if `'` can be escaped with a `\` for example.

A quick explanation:

The following: `([^']*'[^']*')*` will match 0 or an even number of single quotes with non quotes in between, and `[^']*$` matches any non-quotes and the end-of-string.

So, the complete regex `substr(?=([^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)` matches any `"substr"` that has 0 or an even number of single quotes ahead of it, *when looking all the way to the end-of-string!*

Looking all the way to the end-of-string is the key here. If you wouldn't do that, the following `"substr"` would also be replaced:

```
aaa 'substr' bbb 'ccc ddd' eee
           ^     ^       ^
           |     |       |
           i     ii     iii
```

because it "sees" an even number of single quotes ahead of it (**i** and **ii**). You must force it to look at the entire string to the right of it (all the way to `$`)!

Comment: Many thanks Bart! Somehow I got stuck to copying and never thought of looking ahead.